# .net compressing pdf generated with crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, crystal-reports, compression

As of now, we are generating PDFs programmatically using crystal reports and saving it to database. The PDF document has barcode image in it. Each file is of size 120-150 KB.

Everything is running fine but lately we are facing problem with huge growth in database size and storage requirements. This is due to 100 - 1000 records being generated each day.

Is there any way to compress the PDF files and then store it. Any API/tools available that perform these without creating issue to the barcode.Can we gain much reduction in size after compression?

Or any alternative way of storing the data will be good?

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sveerap

Comment: Is storing the pdf on the filesystem and only storing the path to the pdf in the DB an option?

Comment: @MikeBantegui: I had already suggested this approach but the business is not interested in storing the pdfs on the file system

Comment: You do realize that the database is just a file, right? They are already stored on the filesystem. ;-) You could use SQL Server **Filestreams** or better yet, **Filetables** for better integration. Backup and restore capabilities are fully integrated with filestreams and filetables. You could create a separate local volume for just storing the PDFs.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you won't gain *much* by compressing a PDF as it is already compressed.

Answer (score 2):

Many *compressed* PDF files can be compressed further.

Size of a PDF file can usually be decreased by:

- removing unused objects (if any)
- removing extra whitespace characters from the file (not from the visual content)
- using object streams (a PDF 1.5 feature)

I do not know how well Crystal Report compresses PDFs but you might want to try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) and the following code and see if your files can be compressed better.

```
public static void CompressExistingDocument(string original, string output)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(original))
    {
        pdf.SaveOptions.Compression = PdfCompression.Flate;
        pdf.SaveOptions.UseObjectStreams = true;
        pdf.SaveOptions.RemoveUnusedObjects = true;
        pdf.SaveOptions.WriteWithoutFormatting = true;

        pdf.Save(output);
    }

    FileInfo originalFileInfo = new FileInfo(original);
    FileInfo compressedFileInfo = new FileInfo(output);
    MessageBox.Show(
        String.Format("Original file size: {0} bytes;\r\nCompressed file size: {1} bytes",
        originalFileInfo.Length, compressedFileInfo.Length));

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(output);
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.